# Write Text to a QTextEdit Box From a C Function

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp, client, qtextedit

I don't have a specific example to show... but what I am looking to do is from a C based file, write text from a TCP Socket to a QTextEdit box (which is read only).

I'm writing a little TCP client that reads incoming data from a TCP Server I wrote in C for Linux. Now I'm trying to write a QT GUI based client so a user can send/receive text from the server. Essentially it's a chat server.

I am not sure how to write specifically to a QTextEdit control directly from a c file. My socket code is strictly C based and I can get QT to trigger the function that opens the socket etc. For now, I am trying to figure out how to read anything the server responds with.

While there is incoming data, how do I go about passing that buffer back through the QT framework and into the QTextEdit control? I'm using the C function recv().

Answer (score 0):

QTextEdit has setPlainText API which allow to modify text which it displays. some how you need to access this API from you c code, by exposing QTextEdit object or some function that call setPlainText API on QTextEdit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write a c++ class in another file, and include it in your c file.
That class will need to be something like this:

```
class MySignalClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    void send_message(char *x)
    {
         emit message_to_write(x);
    }
signals:

    void message_to_write(char * x);

};
MySignalClass obj;
```

You will also need to create a slot in the class where your QEditBox is. After That if you connect this signal to that slot. The slot you create will modify the contents of your QEditBox with the stuff you send with the signal.

To send the signal, all you need to do is after you call recv(), insert this line

obj.send_message(buffer); //where buffer is what you got with recv().

I'm not sure if this is enough, you could look some more over the Qt signal and slot mechanism [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

This is more of a c++ solution, I don't know how you could send a Qt signal without having a class.